# iOS PopOver - only from bar button item or round rect?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview, popover

Im building an iPad app which has a tableview embeded within a UIview (odd, i know). In the UITableview there is data loaded in via a PLIST. I want to allow a user to "select" a row and it would show a "popover" (uiview) containing a textfield allowing them to edit that field.

However, looking through the code i see there are only two ways to fire the function:

- presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem
- presentPopoverFromRect

IS this true, can you only fire that function from either a round rect or a bar button item? I have a feeling i can be done, however searching has not turned up any answers.

Comment: can't you trigger the popover with one of this method?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can only present a popover from a bar button item or from a rect in a view.

From the [official doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
Presenting and Dismissing the Popover
– presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:
– presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:
– dismissPopoverAnimated:
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are the only two ways to present a subclass of UIPopoverController.  It is not clear in your question as to why "presentPopoverFromRect" wouldn't work.

I understand that "presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem" is a bit limiting but "presentPopoverFromRect" lets you do whatever you want.  It allows you to position a popover relative to a view where the "rect" provides a way to offset the popover relative to the view's frame.

Try:

```
CGRect popoverRectFromCell = CGRectMake(tappedCell.frame.size.width / 2, tappedCell.frame.size.height / 2, 1, 1);

[cellPopover presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRectFromCell 
                             inView:tappedCell 
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp 
                           animated:YES];
```

Of course you can tweak the "popoverRectFromCell" to achieve desired results.

However, I am not sure this is really a use-case for a UIPopoverController.  Might be easier to just make a custom view and use that for text input when the user taps a cell.

Comment: I wanted to first see if it was possible with the "built-in" functionality, but it seems going the custom route will better suffice.

Comment: So i figure I can use the *selected_cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton* function which will create an inline "button" -- this actually would not interfere with my interface (i have requirements). Anyone know how to tap into it to fire off the popover command?

Comment: But your popover and tableview are not in the same view - right? what you need to do is to make the controller that contains the view that will show your popover the delegate of your table view and when the user tap on a cell trigger the display of the popover through either a button or a rectangle area of this view (that's the parent view of the popover)